# Scalable WCF Web Service

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, scalability, load-balancing

I have written a stateless WCF REST Web service. The main consumer of this web service will be a mobile app. There could be 1000's of clients connecting to the web service simultaneously. And this number will increase in the future.

How do I deploy the WCF web service so that it scales nicely. I am guessing the web service will be hosted in multiple servers and a load balancer will distribute the traffic among there servers. Can anyone suggest a load balancer typically used for such a scenario?

Is there any other recommended way to deploy the web service for scalability?

Answer (score 0):

Frankly speaking I haven't tried this... So this only a thought

I would Install Microsoft Azure Service Bus for Windows Server and then connect/setup all available instances of Web Service to the Service bus endpoint. 
There is a buildin load balancer.

Pros:
There is a build in Load Balancer, easy.